# Xamarin.Forms Picker Issue with SelectedItem not showing the bound value

Tags: xamarin, picker, selecteditem

I have a problem with my Xamarin.Forms app, specifically with a Picker which does not show the actual value of the SelectedItem property. I searched all available threads but none solved my issue. I have a ListView page with an ObservableCollection of "Surgery" objects, each having a property of type "Category" (see below).

```
public class Surgery 
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Category))]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category 
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<Surgery> Surgeries { get; set; }

}
```

I also have an EditPage with a picker:

```
      <Picker Title="Category" x:Name="categoryPicker" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}"                               
              ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
      />
```

And the corresponding EditPageViewModel:

```
public class EditPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Surgery Surgery { get; set; }
    public Command LoadCategoriesCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () => await LoadCategoriesExecute());
        }
    }
    public List<Category> categories;

    public EditPageViewModel(Surgery surgery = null)
    {
        LoadCategoriesCommand.Execute(null);
        Surgery = surgery ?? new Surgery { Date = DateTime.Today };                                                           
    }

    async Task LoadCategoriesExecute()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Categories = await App.DataService.GetAllCategoriesAsync();                
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public string SurgeryName
    {
        get { return Surgery.Name; }
        set
        {
            Surgery.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DateTime SurgeryDate
    {
        get { return Surgery.Date; }
        set
        {
            Surgery.Date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Category SelectedCategory
    {
        get { return Surgery.Category; }
        set
        {
            if(Surgery.Category != value)
                Surgery.Category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<Category> Categories
    {
        get { return categories; }
        set
        {
            categories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Creating a new Surgery object works perfectly fine with this code. It is saved to the database und displayed in the ListView page. The picker displays the List correctly and the Category can be chosen (which is also reflected in the UI).

THE PROBLEM: When I try to edit a Surgery object with a set Category property, the EditPage displays all properties and the corresponding value correctly except for the picker. The items are loaded and are also bound to the ItemSource - however, the picker is not set to the actual Category property of the Surgery object. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this is because SelectedCategory needs to be one of the values from Categories.  The way your model is constructed they are two different objects containing the same data, rather than two different references to the same object.

Comment: Alright, and at what point should I make a reference of the SelectedCategory to the Categories list which is populating the picker, and how?

Comment: @FabianK You mean that you want to display picker correct value when you choose one Surgery?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Exactly! I believe I managed to solve the problem! I simply added the following statement to the finally section of LoadCategoriesExecute()
`SelectedCategory = Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Surgery.CategoryId);`
Now it does show the previously chosen category when trying to edit an existing Surgery. 
Thanks @Jason for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define properties in your models with INotifyPropertyChanged like in your viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I guess @Jason was right that SelectedCategory must reference a value of Categories. Also, why would implement INotifyPropertyChanged twice (model & viewmodel) make any difference? I thought one implements it either in the model OR the viewmodel